# Calling method from module in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I call a method from a module in a view?

Made in /lib folder "util.rb"

```
module Util
  def something
    ....
  end
end
```

in controller

```
require 'util'
```

in view

```
<% name = ??? Util.something ??? %>
```

Comment: either make the method module's singleton method or mixing this module into the object on which you want to get it's methods.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyDeineko

Comment: Also remember this is what Helpers are for in Rails (Helpers are actually modules).  If it's limited to one view this would be an ideal case to use a helper instead of rolling your own.  If not, all files in your lib folder are autoloaded into rails so you can just include the module wherever needed.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be great to see the actual use case as there are a couple of ways to do it. I'd also recommend using a helper for views as that's what they are designed for.

But in your case, the only thing to make it work, is to set a `self` on that method.

```
module Util
  def self.something
    puts 'hi'
  end
end
```

then you can easily call it in your view:

```
<% hello = Util.something %>
```

Comment: This answer helped in bringing me to the conclusion of "include the module in my view helper to enable usage in the view". Thanks